# UITableview delete delete all content in cell after selection

Tags: swift, uitableview, uikit

I have an UITableView
And I have describe cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    
    if indexPath.section == 0{
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: AddressСommentInputTableViewCell.cellId, for: indexPath) as! AddressСommentInputTableViewCell
        
       
        switch indexPath.row {
        case 0:
            cell.cellType = .NAME
            cell.setupCell()
            cell.textEdit.placeholder = "Как Вас зовут"
            cell.textEdit.text = self.profileModel.userName
            
            nameTF = cell.textEdit
            cell.selectionStyle = .none
           // cell.setupCell()
        case 1:
            cell.cellType = .EMAIL
            cell.setupCell()
            cell.textEdit.placeholder = "Ваш email"
            cell.selectionStyle = .none
            cell.textEdit.text = self.profileModel.email
            emailTF = cell.textEdit
        case 2:
            cell.cellType = .PHONE
            cell.selectionStyle = .none
            cell.setupCell()
            cell.textEdit.placeholder = "Ваш телефон"
            
            cell.textEdit.text = self.profileModel.phone
            phoneTF = cell.textEdit
        case 3:
            cell.cellType = .BIRTHDATE
            cell.setupCell()
            cell.textEdit.placeholder = "Дата рождения"
            cell.selectionStyle = .none
            cell.textEdit.text = self.profileModel.birthday
            birthDateTF = cell.textEdit
        default:
            cell.cellType = .NAME
            cell.setupCell()
            
        }
        
      
        cell.selectionStyle = .none
    }
    if indexPath.section == 1 {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: CardDataTableViewCell.cellId, for: indexPath) as! CardDataTableViewCell
        if self.profileModel.paymentInfo == nil {
            cell.setupCell(with: "Добавить карту")
        }
        else {
            cell.setupCell(with:  "         *** "+self.profileModel.paymentInfo!.lastNumbers!)
        }
        cell.selectionStyle = .none
    }
   
  // self.deliveryAddressDataDictionary[self.addressKey] = cell.textEdit
    return UITableViewCell()  
    
}
```

here is setup cell function

func setupCell(){

```
self.addSubview(addressIconLabel)
self.addSubview(textEdit)
self.addSubview(downView)

self.selectionStyle = .none

switch cellType {
case .EMAIL:
    addressIconLabel.text = "w"
    textEdit.isEnabled = false
case .GENDER:
    addressIconLabel.text = "V"
    textEdit.isEnabled = true
case .BIRTHDATE:
    addressIconLabel.text = "v"
    textEdit.isEnabled = true
case .PHONE:
    addressIconLabel.text = "A"
    textEdit.isEnabled = true
case .ADDRESS:
    addressIconLabel.text = "O"
    textEdit.isEnabled = true
case .FAMALYNAME:
    addressIconLabel.text = "y"
    textEdit.isEnabled = true
case .NAME:
    addressIconLabel.text = "y"
    textEdit.isEnabled = true
case .COMMENT:
    addressIconLabel.text = "y"
    textEdit.isEnabled = true
}

if cellType == .ADDRESS {
    addressIconLabel.text = "M"
    textEdit.isEnabled = false
}

if cellType == .COMMENT {
    addressIconLabel.text = "P"
    textEdit.isEnabled = true
}

addressIconLabel.snp.makeConstraints { make in
    make.top.equalTo(self).offset(30)
    make.leading.equalTo(self).offset(20)
    make.width.equalTo(30)
}

textEdit.snp.makeConstraints { make in
    make.centerY.equalTo(addressIconLabel)
    make.trailing.equalTo(self).offset(-20)
    make.leading.equalTo(addressIconLabel.snp.trailing).offset(10)
    make.height.equalTo(60)
}

downView.snp.makeConstraints { make in
    make.top.equalTo(textEdit.snp.bottom).offset(1)
    make.leading.equalTo(textEdit)
    make.trailing.equalTo(textEdit)
    make.height.equalTo(1)
}

if cellType == .ADDRESS {
    textEdit.placeholder = "Введите адрес"
    let address = UserDefaultsWorker.fetchActiveAddress()
    if address != nil {
        textEdit.text = address?.addressString
    }
}
if cellType == .COMMENT{
    textEdit.placeholder = "Комментарий"
}
if cellType == .PHONE {
    textEdit.isEnabled = false
}
```

}

And it runs ok

[image]

But when I select cell (And it really selected, or change in cell UITextField something, it delete all cintent in cell)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I am stupid)
in my if/else condition I didn't return cell and return always
// self.deliveryAddressDataDictionary[self.addressKey] = cell.textEdit
return UITableViewCell()

Thats why I have took a problems